# How to access a yaml in rails config path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, yaml

I'm writting a ruby gem and I want to let user use your own yaml file configuration, but I don't know how to test if the user_config.yml exists into rails config path.
I want to use user_config.yml only if this file exists into config path.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Rails.root` (or `RAILS_ROOT` in earlier versions of Rails) gives you the path of the application root. From there, you can see if the file you're interested in exists.

e.g.

```
path = File.join(Rails.root, "config", "user_config.yml")
if File.exists?(path)
  # do something
end
```

Comment: These days you'd probably use `Rails.root.join('config', 'user_config.yml')`

Answer (score 1):

you can access your Rails App's load path with the $LOAD_PATH variable which is of type Array.

Thus

```
if $LOAD_PATH.include?('/path/where/user/should/put/their/user_config.yml')
  # EDIT
  config_options = File.new('rails_app/config/user_config.yml', 'r')
else
  # EDIT
  config_options = File.new('path/to/default/config.yml', 'r')
end
```

There is also another useful method for the [Ruby File class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#) called #exists? which will of course check to see if a file exists. See File class docs for more.

Hope this gets you started. Your question was rather vague, reply with more details if you need more help.

Comment: Sorry, it was hard to explain. If I have the user_config.yml into the config path (rails_app/config/user_config.yml), how can I access that file? Can I use something like that: YAML.load_file("#{$LOAD_PATH}/config/user_config.yml")?

Comment: As I said in my original answer the $LOAD_PATH variable is an array so you wouldn't want to use string interpolation. See the edits in my answer for suggestions on loading files.

Comment: @BrunnoDosSantos To get a hash from your yaml, you can indeed use the YAML module. `configs_hash = YAML.load_file("path/to/config.yml")[RAILS_ENV]`, where `RAILS_ENV` is 'development', 'test', etc.

Comment: Luke, I'm sorry again... but I want to know how to use 'rails_app/config' dinamically. As I said, I'm writing this code inside a gem, and I don't know what is the rails_app path. That was I wanted to ask in my original question.